# How to sort folders above files with QSortFilterProxyModel?

Tags: python, qt, sorting

I have a `QTreeView` with a `QFileSystemModel` which is filtered by `QSortFilterProxyModel`. Now I would like to have all folders in `QTreeView` above the normal files/links like it is by default in Nautilus and Dolphin. The proxy only sort by alphabetic order by now. I'm sure I'd have to create a `Qt.UserRole` ([Qt.ItemDataRole](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)) but I've no clue how to do that.

```
import sys
import os

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self._view = QTreeView()
        self._view.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self._view.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self._view.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self._view.setItemsExpandable(False)
        self._view.setDragEnabled(False)

        self._view.header().setClickable(True)
        self._view.header().setMovable(False)
        self._view.header().setSortIndicatorShown(True)

        layout.addWidget(self._view)

        # Add the model
        self._model = QFileSystemModel()
        self._model.setRootPath(QDir().rootPath())
        self._model.setReadOnly(False)
        self._model.setFilter(QDir.AllDirs | QDir.AllEntries)

        # Add sort proxy
        self._proxy = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self._proxy.setSourceModel(self._model)
        self._view.setModel(self._proxy)

        # sorting
        self._view.header().setSortIndicator(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self._proxy.sort(self._view.header().sortIndicatorSection(),
                         self._view.header().sortIndicatorOrder() )
        QObject.connect(self._view.header(),
                        SIGNAL('sortIndicatorChanged(int,Qt::SortOrder)'),
                        self._proxy.sort )

        # Root path
        path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        self._model.setRootPath(path)

        # Set a root index
        source_index = self._model.index(path)
        index = self._proxy.mapFromSource(source_index)
        self._view.setRootIndex(index)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: set the sort key to `lambda x:(not os.path.isdir(x),x)`

Comment: Looks like I'm blind today. Can you please point me where to find that sort key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is lot easier! Just use source model for sort instead of proxy

```
        # sorting
        self._view.header().setSortIndicator(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self._model.sort(self._view.header().sortIndicatorSection(),
                         self._view.header().sortIndicatorOrder() )
        QObject.connect(self._view.header(),
                        SIGNAL('sortIndicatorChanged(int,Qt::SortOrder)'),
                        self._model.sort )
```

BTW Question was missleading. I used `QSortFilterProxyModel` only to filter not sort.

Answer (score 1):

Custom sorting behavior is achieved by subclassing QSortFilterProxyModel and reimplementing `lessThan()`

from the docs ...

```
class MySortFilter(QSortFilterProxyModel):
   def lessThan(self,left,right):   
       leftData = self.sourceModel().data(left)
       rightData = self.sourceModel().data(right)
       leftPath = os.path.abspath(str(leftData.toUrl().toLocalFile() ))
       rightPath = os.path.abspath(str(rightData.toUrl().toLocalFile() ))
       return (not os.path.isdir(leftPath),leftPath)< (not os.path.isdir(rightPath),rightPath )

#now use this class instead of QSortFilterProxyModel
```

I think would work from reading the docs ... Im not very familliar with QT though so this is just what I got from the docs

Comment: Thanks Joran. But I'm getting `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, QVariant found` in isdir.

Comment: yeah Im not sure how to get the actual value ... like I said not too familiar with QT leftData and rightData should both be filepaths

Comment: Thanks a million again, Joran. I finally got it working (see my edit in your answer). The path is not pretty but it'll work.