# Sorted by number in QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I would like show any content in folder with following Code:

```
self.file = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select Image Directory", dirpath))
model = QFileSystemModel()
model.setRootPath(QDir.currentPath())
```

I need the files sorted by number?

**[1,10,100,1000,2,20,200..] to [1,2,10,20,100,200..]**

How can I do this??

Comment: You need to use a `QSortFilterProxyModel` to get custom sorting on the `QFileSystemModel`. This can be done by reimplementing [lessThan](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#lessThan) in a subclass. There is [a related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20006775/984421) that involves using this approach.

Comment: Do you want to show the sorted list in a custom file list view or in the file dialog? In the first case, the solution suggested by @ekhumoro is a good starting point, but in the second it's impossible, as `getExistingDirectory` is a static function that creates the dialog for which there's no control over its sorting mechanisms.

Comment: @musicamante It's only impossible if you insist on using the static functions. Otherwise, there's [QFileDialog.setProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setProxyModel).

Comment: @ekhumoro right, I wasn't clear about that, sorry.